# Split action bar search view on bottom when iconified, on top when expanded

Tags: android, android-actionbar, splitactionbar

Is there an easy way to make the search view open to the top action bar but keep the iconified search view on the bottom action bar when using a split action bar? Google Mail as well as Google Maps seem to do this. Do you have to manually hide and show the items or is there a way to tell the system do that automatically?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What evidence do you have that the magnifying glass on the bottom action bar is an iconified search view, versus just a regular action item? I would assume that it's a regular action item, triggering adding the search view as a custom view to the main action bar when clicked.

Comment: Absolutely no evidence. That's why I'm asking here. I'm hoping I wouldn't have to do it manually and that there would be a flag that I've just missed.

Comment: Ah, OK. Have you run **`uiautomatorviewer`**, to see if it is a `SearchView`, either iconified or expanded? This is Google; they certainly roll their own widgets from time to time.

Comment: That's the normal behaviour when using the SearchView with splitActionBarWhenNarrow. Expansion of expandable Actionviews always takes place at the top. As soon as the expanded ActionView is visible the icons in the split actionbar disappear.